# cefsharp wpf фоновые клики по координатам в своем же окне

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

Существует ли способ фонового(когда приложение свернуто) нажатия кнопок на сайте через cefsharp (встраивание скриптов `Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync` не на всех сайтах работает).

Или же клики по координатам в своем же окне wpf(когда приложение свернуто).

Comment: `Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync` и есть тот самый способ, и работает он на всех сайтах, просто скрипты, которые вы пишете не на всех сайтах работают.

Comment: @aepot не у всех кнопок на сайте идет eventlistener click.

Comment: кпопка.click();

Comment: @aepot я уже пробывал, но это не работает. Задавал вопрос тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1281478/%d0%98%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0

Comment: возможно не срабатывает, потому что нет фокуса на окне, когда оно свёрнуто и в хром не работает - window.focus();, то же сталкивался с таким в яндексе, работал с другой библиотекой на хроумиме, у меня не проверялись введённые данные в форме, пока окно не получит фокус, например через wpfwindow.Activate(); но в многопотоке это ужас. у меня тогда решилось тем, что при создании окна wpf с элементом браузера я не вызывал wpfwindow.Show(); работал с таким окнами и в окнах браузеров был фокус (делал скрины браузера после каждого ввода в формы и всё засчитывалось)

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир самое интересное что на python через xpatch все работает

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир не знаете почему не работает даже через консоль в хроме ?

Comment: Пробывал даже так document.evaluate('//div[@class="header__login"]//button', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,null). singleNodeValue.click();

Comment: не работает, потому что, там возможно проверка есть - есть ли у окна фокус, и если его нет, то ничего не происходит при клике. кроме этого, так же может быть проверка - есть ли наведение мышки на элемент перед кликом, событие mouseover, и если его нет, значит клик не настоящий и не надо ничего делать

Comment: когда в консоли проверяете - то так же - нет фокуса на окне и всего остального